# Is it possible to return a different number of values based on how many variables are assigned to the function?

Tags: function, go, return, variable-assignment

I have a function, `foo()`, that returns an `int` and a `bool`, the `bool` being whether or not the function executed properly. If the caller only wants the `int`, he can type `value, _ := foo()`. Is there a way to set it so that the caller can just type `value := foo()` and it automatically only returns the `int`, like how `range` can return either the index and value, or just the index?

Example code:

```
func foo(num int) (int, bool) {
    if num % 2 == 1 {
        //function fails
        return 0, false
    }

    //function succeeds
    return num + 5, true
}

func main() {
    value1, _ := foo(6) //works

    value2 := foo(6) //assignment mismatch
}
```

Comment: No there is no way to make a function do what you want. If the function call is the RHS of an assignment, then the LHS MUST list an identifier for every single value the function returns. _Only_ for-range, map index expressions, type assertions, and channel receives allow the special form of assignment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Special features of the Go programming language include maps, type assertions, `for` statement with a `range` clause and channel receives have variable number of return values. But the number of return values cannot be variable for a regular function type.

- Maps

```golang
m := make(map[string]int)

m["one"] = 1

// Return value is the value in the map for the given key.
val := m["one"] 

// First return value is the value in the map for the given
// key and second return value indicates if the key was
// present in the map.
val,ok := m["one"]
```

- `for` statement with a `range` clause

```golang
arr := []int{1, 2, 3, 4}

// Return value is the index.
for idx := range arr {
 ...
}

// First return value is the index and second return 
// value is a copy of the element at that index.
for idx, val := range arr {
 ...
}
```

- Type assertions

```golang
var i interface{}
i = 1

// First return value is the underlying value and second
// return value is a boolean value that reports whether the
// assertion succeeded or not.
num, ok := i.(int)

// Return value is the underlying value.
num := i.(int)
```

- Channels receives

```golang
c := make(chan int, 2)

c <- 12
c <- 21

// Return value indicates the received value from the channel.
val := <-c

// First return value is the received value from the
// channel. Second return value is a boolean which indicates
// if there are no more values to receive and the channel is
// closed or not.
val, ok := <-c
```